# Notation explanation: $\Omega(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, finite-groups, group-actions

The following theorem is stated in Kurzweil and Stellmacher:

> Suppose that the action of a group $A$ on an Abelian group $V$  is coprime and $A$ acts trivially on $\Omega(V)$. Then $A$ acts trivially on $V$.

What is the notation $\Omega(V)$ here? In the text, the authors define $\Omega(G)$ as $$\Omega(G)=\langle x\in G:x^p=1\rangle,$$ where $G$ is a $p$-group. However, I couldn't find this notation for a general group.

Comment: Is there any indication in your textbook that $V$ is not a finite $p$-group?

Comment: @user170231 Yes, the section starts with: Let $V$ be an Abelian group.  In fact, further down there is a theorem which is stated for the case when $V$ is a $p$-group.

Comment: What page is this on?

Comment: 8.4.3 on Page 198.

Comment: Well, $V$ is an abelian group of odd order, which doesn't seem to be mentioned in the statement. Then $\Omega(V)$ can be taken to be the product of $\Omega_1(V_p)$ for $V_p$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $V$. But the restriction to $|V|$ odd is necessary here.

Comment: But no where in the section does it say that order of $V$ is odd. It could be even and the order of $A$ could be odd?

Comment: No, I'm saying that if $|V|$ is even the statement is false. $V=Q_8$ has an automorphism of order $3$ that centralizes $\Omega(V)$. For $p=2$ you need to centralize $\Omega_2(V)$ to obtain the same conclusion.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Alright, thanks!

Comment: @DavidA.Craven But $V$ is an abelian group in 8.4.3. I would guess that $\Omega(V)$ is the direct product of $\Omega(P)$ over the Sylow $p$-subgroups $P$ of $V$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ah yes, you are right. I hate standing assumptions in sections. Put your assumptions in the statements of the theorems.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, I did write in my original post that $V$ is Abelian.

Comment: @Guest For abelian groups if $A$ acts trivially and coprimely on $\Omega_1(P)$ for $P$ an abelian $p$-group then $A=1$. For *odd primes*, one can drop the word abelian here, which is why I got confused, as it's the exact same statement.

Comment: @DerekHolt The direct product notation, you suggested makes sense but I find it a little strange that it is not stated explicitly in the book.

Comment: I agree it's weird it hasn't been mentioned, but it's the only reasonable meaning for it.

Comment: I have never come across a textbook that did not contain the occasional (or in some cases frequent) minor error or oversight. I would guess that they were thinking of $V$ as an abelian $p$-group when they wrote this corollary, but forgot to say so.